# UIScrollView and image thumbnails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to have a scroll view, where you display 5 thumbnails on the scroll view each time. 
Basically it's a table with one row and in each row we have 5 thumbnails in it.
You slide your finger to the right then you display the next set of 5 thumbnails.

What do I need to do this?? Is it true that we need a scroll view to do this? How can I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UIView that will contain your UIScrollView, place (something like) this code in -viewDidLoad:

```
UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
pageWidth = screen.bounds.size.height;
pageHeight = screen.bounds.size.width;


scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, pageWidth, pageHeight)];
[scrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numPages * pageWidth, pageHeight)];
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth, 0)];
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
[scrollView setDelegate:self];
[scrollView setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:NO];
[scrollView setOpaque:YES];

[self.view insertSubview:scrollView atIndex:0];
[scrollView release];

// iterate through your thumbnails - which are UIViews
thumbnailViews = [NSMutableArray array];
[thumbnailViews retain];
NSUInteger pageCounter = 0;

for (...)
    {
    ThumbnailView *thumbnailView = [[ThumbnailView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( pageCounter*pageWidth, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight )];
    [thumbnailView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [thumbnailView setViewController:self]; // this may be necessary to push/pop on navigation controller stack.
    [thumbnailView restoreState];
    [scrollView thumbnailView];
    [thumbnailViews thumbnailView];
    ++pageCounter;
}
```

In my case, pageWidth, pageHeight, thumbnailViews and scrollView are all ivars for my UIView subclass.

Comment: could you explain a bit what UIScreen means?

Comment: In my case I wanted each 'thumbnail' to fill the available screen space. If you are happy with a smaller area, then you could define pageWidth/pageHeight according. From <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html> : "A UIScreen object contains the bounding rectangle of the device’s entire screen. When setting up your application’s user interface, you should use the properties of this object to get the recommended frame rectangles for your application’s window."

Comment: so you're saying that this scroll view will fill up the entire view?

Comment: Yes, minus status, navigation and tool bars.

Comment: a very noob question, this is you are initializing the scroll view via code right?

Comment: Yes. It's all in code here. I tend to prefer code in most cases - especially in a case like this where you might want to have an arbitrary number of thumbnails. That said, I might create a NIB/XIB for the ThumbnailView if it were going to be more than just a UIView with an image. If, for example, double tapping revealed some information overlay... you know, that kind of thing.

Comment: A subclass of UIView that you will create. It need not be called ThumbnailView. You could probably just UIImageView to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked in here as I'm learning about `UIScrollView`s myself.  I started to try and get westsider's code to work, but I noticed that it is practically gobblygook.  It should be in a `UIViewController` that implements the `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` protocol, and things like `[scrollView thumbnailView];` is meaningless as here `thumbnailView` is a method name.  I believe http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46556/How-To-Use-UIScrollView-in-Your-iPhone-App.aspx is more coherent.

To answer the question, I think you want to create a `UIScrollView` in a standard manner--such as in the link, and you want to create a subclass of `UIView` called, say, `UIView5` that has 5 `UIImageViews`.  Then, instead of adding a normal `UIView` to the `UIScrollView`, like `[scrollView addSubview:standardUIView];`, you add `UIView5` objects.